# Hive SQL querying struct columns

Tags: sql, hive

I have the following table setup

```
mytable(table)
  foods(array<struct<pizza<struct<cheese:string, meat:string, mushroom,string> pancake:string>)
    pizza(array)
      cheese(string)
      meat(string)
      mushroom(string)
    pancake(string)
```

I'm trying to select a single column from the pizza array I am using

```
select foods.pizza.cheese from mytable;
```

But I get this error:

> Operator is only supported on struct or list of struct types

Is there a way I can select those columns on an individual level?

Comment: What's the comple description of your table? `foods(array<struct<)` is incomplete!